# Update JSON file write not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file

I'm trying to read existing JSON file and update the existing value and saving it back. I'm getting below error message:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'src/myApp/test.json'
Require stack:
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
}
```

Please find the code below -

Much appreciated if someone can help me to fix this issue.

**test.json**

```
{
    "key": ""
}
```

**updateJSON.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileName = 'src/myApp/test.json';
const file = require(fileName);
    
file.key = "new value";
    
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file), function writeJSON(err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
  console.log('writing to ' + fileName);
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getitng ?

Comment: I ran the exact same code and the value is getting written into the file

Comment: Updated my post - can you please check and help me to fix this.

Comment: Check user5579894 answer. It should help you

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Error: Cannot find module 'src/myApp/test.json'` indicates that the Node.js cannot resolve the `src/myApp/test.json` file correctly.

By default, the name(`src/myApp/test.json` here) not starting with `./` will be recognized as a `module` of Node.js and will be resolved from `native modules` and `node_modules`,  which leads to the error.

Using a relative path like `../src/myApp/test.json` should fix it.

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id